# wp_enqueue_script + how to load JS or CSS in one URL merge call?

Tags: css, functions, wp-enqueue-script

Is there any proper wordpress way of including the JS and CSS through one merged URL?

So that instead of loading in x number of separate calls for each JS asset, it can be all merged into one URL?  Samething for CSS.

I know this is easy enough to do using straight up PHP, but I wanted to check if wordpress has some nifty way of combining requests.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress core has not such a mechanism. I've seen Caching plugins who do this. One of them is [Semiologic Cache (Wordpress Pluin)](http://www.semiologic.com/software/sem-cache/) and there are probably others who do this as well.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is not automated is because it would wreak havoc on sites. Many plugins, themes, etc have multiple CSS/JS files that conflict when merged.

With a plugin like the one mentioned above you basically have to add the files manually one by one, and see if it breaks anything.

The alternative, which is a way better method but time consuming, is to look into the syntax yourself and combine them manually to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting that while WP is capable of and does use script concatenation in admin area - it is not exposed or suggested to be used in site itself.

I suppose with some tinkering it might be possible to make use of core, but it is way easier to make use of existing plugins.

I use [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/), it has extensive CSS/script concatenation support.

Comment: thanks... that looks like a good caching plugin.  I'm trying to go no plugin route because I want it to be a one-click theme install.

Comment: @AndreLiem - for one-click, place the plugin in a subdirectory of your theme and load it manually. plugins are just php includes.

Comment: thanks hakre, I actually meant that by installing a theme it comes pre-ready with caching.  I'm working on distributing a theme with a bunch of features built in.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the plugin [autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) that does exactly that. It is well supported and easy to set up.